# ImportError: cannot import name getoutput

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, python-2to3

I am using `future` to port code from Python 2 to Python 3.

Upon futurizing `getoutput`, the import changes from

`from commands import getoutput` to `from subprocess import getoutput`

And my code uses `getoutput` in testing a requirements file.

However, when I run the test, I get the following error:

```
from subprocess import getoutput
ImportError: cannot import name getoutput
```

How do I avoid this? Or is there any other alternative that could be used for futurizing `getoutput` from Python2 to Python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the major version of a Python installation using the `sys.version_info` object, which has a `major` attribute. You can then check this value to see if you're running on Python 2 or Python 3+.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    from commands import getoutput
else:
    from subprocess import getoutput
```

This will work if there are few conditional imports and other simple statements. Otherwise, you could look at a compatibility package like [`six`](https://pypi.org/project/six/), which is used for letting you run code in both 2 and 3 by giving you certain layers. Six contains a module `six.moves`, which contains `six.moves.getoutput`, which will resolve the `getoutput` properly. (It is equivalent to `commands.getoutput` in 2.7 and `subprocess.getoutput` in 3+).

Another alternative would be to use a try-except block around your imports, and let it resolve itself.

```
try:
    from subprocess import getoutput
except ImportError:
    from commands import getoutput
```

Comment: The code base is huge. So I am avoiding to use `try except`

Comment: @Deesha without using a conversion dependency, you would need to either if/else or try/except logic. However, I looked and six contains a rename which handles this case out of the box. I updated my answer, and you might want to use that, especially if you run into any other porting problems.

Comment: Yes. I looked around and found even `future.moves` works. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

I saw that I was missing the install alias statement:

```
from future import standard_library
standard_library.install_aliases()
from subprocess import getoutput
```

However, this gave a `PEP-8` error: `Module level import not at top of file`

So I used `future.moves` instead as:

`from future.moves.subprocess import getoutput`

And it works.